# auto highlight active cell find duplicates google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQsUI.jpg)

active cell will highlight match words in same sheet

active cell will highlight match words in same sheet

active cell will highlight match words in same sheet

active cell will highlight match words in same sheet
active cell will highlight match words in same sheet

Comment: here is demo file i try but not working https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13qz11eSy8ODHs9Cs-0lVf7AGnp8C93fSg5FidWcggTg/edit#gid=223895317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've only provided a photo of your data, I've copied the first five to replicate what you'd like to accomplish.

You may use the following code as a reference for what you'd like to do:

```
function checkCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var aCell = cell.getValue();
  var highlight = ss.getRange(1, 3, ss.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < highlight.length; i++) {
    if (highlight[i].toString().includes(aCell)) {
      ss.getRange('C' + (i + 1)).setBackground('#90EE90');
    }
  }
}
```

### OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT1]

I also added a button to run the script automatically to make it easier for you.

### UPDATE

I see that the value of `F2` is located in column `B`. I've updated my code to only start highlighting the other cells when you click on a value in that column. You may use the following code as a reference for what you'd like to do:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow()
  var col = range.getColumn()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getRange(row, col).getValue();
  var highlight = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  if (col == 2) {
    highlight.forEach((x, a) => {
      x.forEach((y, b) => {
        if (y.toString().includes(cell)) {
          ss.getRange(a + 1, b + 1).setBackground('#90EE90');
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

### OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT2]

### REFERENCES

- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

Comment: hi sir, thank you i put the demo link for test, i tried scripts are not working Kindly check it again https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13qz11eSy8ODHs9Cs-0lVf7AGnp8C93fSg5FidWcggTg/edit#gid=223895317

Comment: From the document that you have shared, what's the column where you'll select the cell and the one that will be highlighted?

Comment: Sir, F2 (click from the mouse ) or left or right arrow button from the keyboard where its go highlights match cell then it will highlight See the yellow highlight

Comment: Allow me to look into what you would like to accomplish. The code I provided was solely for the data that you provided in the initial screenshot of the post.

Comment: Sir, is not working Please Look into it one more time, please Here is link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13qz11eSy8ODHs9Cs-0lVf7AGnp8C93fSg5FidWcggTg/edit#gid=223895317

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample output of what you'd like to do. If my answer helped you with your question, please click the accept button on the left, which is the check icon, and upvote it. By doing so, other people in the community who may have the same concern as you would know how their concern would be resolved. If it's unavailable, feel free to tell me. [How to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Yes, it's Working Thank you so much it takes times 2 seconds but that's fine. the only issue is that once I go to another cell the old one highlight will not undo or back to by default for that I have to re-change manually the page if it is possible that would be great Sir, Thanks Again for your time

Comment: some error comes when I apply to main sheets https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t5QHpG9HA0wqjKzeZJfBjCR4jbcOxBNm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I recommend that you post another question for the concern that you have with clearing the format of the cell within the code. As for the error that you are getting, you can just disregard it since it will still highlight the cells when you click on a cell in column B.

Comment: Sir, posted check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77022382/google-sheets-active-cell-highlight-and-un-highlight-concern-that-you-have-with